# Why do inequalities work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $-3x+4 > -x+2$
>
> *Let* $f(x)=-3x+4$
>
> *Let* $g(x)= -x+2$

> *Find all values of* $x, x ∈
>   R$.

I don't understand how can inequalities yield correct answers.

For instance, in the example above, it was **assumed** $f(x)$ is bigger than $g(x)$ and it worked out correctly: $(x<1)$!

I understand where $1$ is coming from, it's the value of $x$ where the two functions meet— *and that's why I actually view inequalities as equivalences to equations (as long there's no division or multiplication by a negative number)*. What I don't understand is how we know that the inequality is true when it's smaller than $1$? What if it was true, when it was *bigger* than one?

We assumed the direction of the inequality sign in the very beginning and we also assumed the direction of the inequality sign in the answer. And we got a numerical answer ($1$) just because it's as if it's an equation anyway. Yet despite all of this assumptions, we got the correct domain!

I know that one function can be bigger in some areas of the graph but smaller in other areas. But what I don't understand is how can the value where the two functions meet (where they may also change direction and start to be lower or bigger than the other function) help us decide how to put our inequality sign. How can we know without looking at a graph!!

I feel like I'm questioning very basic mathematics, but I really can't wrap my head around this :(

NB: I'm aware that quadratic inequalities require a graph and absolute value ones would require a range/ graph as well to be solved correctly. But why don't linear ones require graphs as well!

Comment: Indeed what you wrote in the first three lines is neither a question nor an answer. You need some context. Is $x$ a quantity that we already know something about? Are we asked to find all $x$ that satisfy the inequality? Is the inequality merely one constraint on some other question involving $x$?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ were previously defined then the equations involving them mean something different than if this is the first time they are mentioned (in which case these equations are *definitions* of $f$ and $g$).

Comment: @Davidk Yes, we're asked to find all x
 that satisfy the inequality where x belongs to real numbers

Comment: Now we know what problem you were given to solve. The rest of your question consists of complaints about parts of the solution that made no sense to you, but since you did not show us what the "solution" is, we have no way to respond to your complaints. Are you complaining about someone else's solution, or are you discussing your own approach (converting the inequality to an equation first)? Can you edit the question to first show the "solution" in its entirety before you start commenting on it?

Comment: By the way, quadratic inequalities and inequalities with absolute values also can be solved without a graph. It is a matter of taking the original inequality and applying algebra to find out what the implications of the inequality are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say

> $x-3>4$
>
> $x>4+3$
>
> $x>7$

This inequality works because you **make x stand alone, as if you are getting the value it's equal to** as if you are solving an equation. And when you find the value it's equal to, **x needs to be bigger than that value for x to be greater than the other side**. And even if you subtract 3 from x, you will be doing it to both sides. The equation remains balanced:

> $x>7$
>
> $x-3>7-3$
>
> $x-3>4$

It's like you are going in reverse!

That's why inequalities work.

Answer (score 1):

$-3x + 4 > -x + 2 \iff $

$-3x > -x + 2 + (-4) = -x - 2 \iff$

$3x < x + 2~$

[because when you multiply both sides by -1, you have to reverse the direction of the inequality]

$ \iff $

$2x = 3x + (-x) < 2 \iff $

$x < 1.$

---

The alternative approach of setting

$-3x + 4 = -x + 2 \iff x = 1~$

will not always work for a constraint involving an inequality.  It happened to work in this particular case, but it is not generally valid.  The work done at the start of this answer is the **valid** approach.

For example, consider the second problem of

$$x^2 < 0.$$

Using the alternative (invalid) approach, you conclude that

$x^2 = 0 \iff x = 0.~$

However, the correct answer to this second problem is not $~x < 0.~$

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to a formal algebraic treatment and rules of inequality, i.e. rules of deduction in the context of inequalities taken as axioms closely related to the same principles used for equality.

$0: a<b \lor b<a \lor a=b$: trichotomy property

$I: a <b \implies a+c < b+c$

$II: c>0 \land a<b \implies ac<bc$

$III: c<0 \land a<b \implies bc < ac$

We are given:

$-3x+4 >-x +2 $ :given

$4> 2x+2: $ Rule I, $c=3x$

$2>2x $: Rule I, $c=-2$

$1>x:$ Rule 2, $c=1/2$

---

Less Than and Greater Than are relations but not Equivalence Relations. They deviate from equality in important ways.

An equivalence relation satisfies reflexivity: $a=a$, Symmetry, $a= b \iff b=a$, and $(a=b) \land (b=c) \implies a=c$

These don't apply to inequality generally.

$a<a$ doesn't make sense by the trichotomy property, so we don't have reflexivity.

$a<b $ guarantees $ (b<a)$ is not true so there's no symmetry.

$a<b \land b <c \implies a<c$ so we do have transitivity just like equality.